# how to include php file into drupal 7 custom module

Tags: php, drupal-7, include

I have module name is salesforce_auth

and I have created a folder name includes into my module and I have put my php file into includes folder name is PushToSlackRepository.php

and I have loaded my php file into my module like below:

```
 module_load_include('php', 'salesforce_auth', 'includes/PushToSlackRepository');
```

But its not loading my php file into my module. where I am doing wrong? I am new to drupal and need your help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your salesforce_auth module is installed and enabled.
- Make sure where you have written the call to module_load_include and if it is called indeed?
- Check the output of module_load_include to see if it returns TRUE or
  FALSE.
- If it returns FALSE, run the lines of [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) one by one, to see which path it goes ending up with FALSE? This will give you a clue of the reason behind the problem.